# How to programmatically check if caps lock is on

Tags: vb.net, capslock, intermec

I have an Intermec CK70 device, Is it possible to check programmatically if the caps lock is on? I have tried it on the orange key and green key and they're both working, since it is included in the intermec's source code.

Thanks for the Help. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Visual Basic, you can use:

```
 My.Computer.Keyboard.CapsLock
```

Comment: what I mean is check the caps lock of the device. anyway, thanks for the time answering my question :)

Comment: Have you attempted to use any of the SDK's provided by Intermec? http://www.intermec.com/products/devresourcekit/downloads.aspx

Comment: I had one. which supports the orange and green key, but can't find the caps lock.

Comment: See if any information on the following page assists you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb431750.aspx